# mapping <C-F9> in gvim: no response

Tags: x11, gvim

I'm trying to map `<C-F9>` in gvim (note the "g"). No response. Neither `<C-V><C-F9>` nor `<C-K><C-F9>` produce any response either so I suspect it's not sending any keycode at all if that's possible?

How would I set this up correctly? I've tagged this X11 for now as I suspect it's not gvim at fault here but something lower-level and I don't think it's a termcap issue as there's no terminal involved. That leaves X11 as a likely culprit.

```
$uname -a
Linux box 2.6.32-45-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 2 22:38:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$gvim -version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Nov 15 2012 00:32:35)
Included patches: 1-330
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI. 
...
```

Can post more info on request.

Comment: My gvim responds to `<C-V><C-F9>` just fine, so you're right that gvim is likely not at fault.  I'm guessing your window manager is capturing `<C-F9>`.  What Linux distro and window manager are you using?

Comment: XFCE 4.6.1/XFWM on Xubuntu 10.04 LTS "Lucid" with Gnome 2.30.2.
In fact most CTRL key combinations seem not to work as expected e.g. <C-9> doesn't show up as anything either but <C-V>, <C-K> do work so the control key itself isn't broken.